# JHipster WebFlux H2db initial config notworking

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux, jhipster

When I created jhipster webflux application. After run ./mvnw, I did not login on the webpage.

---

Console Error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.<init>(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

---

java --version : jdk11

jhipster --version : 7.9.2

---

myconfig:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cffRb.png)

yo-rc.json

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "webfluxh2",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1661618234192,
    "cypressAudit": false,
    "cypressCoverage": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.9.2",
    "jwtSecretKey": "",
    "languages": ["en", "fr"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "microfrontend": false,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "com.cevheri.webfluxh2",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": true,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "no",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": ["cypress"],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError Indicates that you use incompatible libraries.

Comment: Hi Jens, When I changed to PostgreSQL, it works.

Comment: Yes, than you also change the driver library

Comment: No, I need the h2 db.

Comment: what I mean is, if you change to pg you have an other dirver, that's why it works.

Comment: Solved jhipster7.9.3 -> this bugfix, https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved jhipster7.9.3 -> this bugfix,
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19380